# Find rows in dataframe with more than one zero

Tags: r

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:
df = data.frame(c(1:5), c(0,0,3,1,0), c(0,2,0,0,0), c(0,0,7,1,2)

```
1 0 0 0
2 0 2 0
3 3 0 7
4 1 0 1
5 0 0 2
```

What should I do so I only get the rows that contain more than one zero?

```
1 0 0 0
2 0 2 0
5 0 0 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: `df[rowSums(df==0) > 1,]`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry, I didn't find that answer before posting mine.

Comment: No problem. People can now use your question as a reference point :)